# Add environment and commands for completion in WinEdt

Tags: winedt

Since version 10.2, Winedt allows completing commands while writing.
Nevertheless, not all commands are possible to be completed.

Is there a way to adds further commands or an environment?

In particular,

```
\begin{definition}

 - 

\end{definition}
```

automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible.

To add commands, open the file `LaTeX.dic` (you can find it in `%B\Dict\LaTeX` folder), add all the commands you want (one per line).

Then sort the file as a dictionary (Tools -> Sort Lines).

[image]

Choose "Dictionary" as a Compare Table, press Sort and then OK.

Save the file and restart WinEdt.

---

To add more environments, it is a bit more complicated. Do the following:

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]
2. Double-click the "Auto Complete" item (`AutoComplete.ini` gets opened)
3. Just before the line

   ```
   END="LaTeX Environments"
   ```

   add the following lines

   ```
       OBJECT="definition"
         MACRO="LetReg(-1,!'  ');"+        // Content placeholder (optionally indented)
               "Exe('%b\Macros\Auto Complete\TeXEnv.edt');"
   ```

   Substitute `definition` and do the same for other environments you want to add.
4. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file.

That's all.

Comment: Thank you for advice. Unfortunately, this does not work for me. Despite I have trying definition theorem proposition lemma.

Comment: Oh sorry but \begin{definition}

Comment: @Zbigniew Please copy and paste the code I've written in WinEdt, because it contains some unprintable characters. Do the same for `proposition` and `lemma`.

Comment: Once again Thank you. Now it does work. Shft+ Ctrl+F9 is breaking I make it  by the macro button